# how to export serial data collected using PySerial to csv file?

Tags: python, csv, serial-port, timestamp, pyserial

I'm trying to collect serial data from a device, timestamp and export it to a .csv file.

The following program writes date and time to csv but not the data returned from the device module:

```
import time
import csv
import fio2

def Csv_creator():
    my_file = open('test_csv.csv', 'w+')

    with my_file:
        new_file = csv.writer(my_file)

def Timestamp():
    date_now = time.strftime('%d/%m/%y')
    time_now = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    return [date_now,time_now]


def Write_loop():
    Csv_creator()
    fio2.Initialize()

    with open('test_csv.csv', 'a') as f:
            csv_file = csv.writer(f)

            for num in range(0,20):

                [date_now,time_now] = Timestamp()
                fio2_data = fio2.Reader()
                print(fio2_data)
                csv_file.writerow([date_now,time_now,fio2_data])   

    Write_loop()
```

The device module is as shown below. It returns the data and I'm able to print it. The only problem is not being able to write it on to the csv file.

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial("COM4",
                    baudrate=2400,
                    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
                    parity =serial.PARITY_ODD)


def Initialize():
    global ser
    try:
        ser.isOpen()
        print("\n Serial is open")
    except: 
        print ("Error: serial Not Open")

def Reader():
    global ser
    if (ser.isOpen()):

        try:                    
            x = ser.readline().decode()
            x = (x)
            return x
        except:
            return "unable to print"
    else: 
        return "cannot open serial port"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I had to remove some garbage letters that were associated with the decimal values. First, I change the received data to string and replaced the garbage letters. Here's how I changed it:

```
[date_now,time_now] = Timestamp()
fio2_data = str(fio2.Reader()).replace("\r\n","")
fio2_data = fio2_data.replace("\x000","")
write_list = [date_now,time_now,fio2_data]
```